# Mac Terminal: Error writing

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm executing this line in Terminal:

```
sudo nano /Applications/Utilities/Boot\ Camp\ Assistant.app/Contents/Info.plist
```

The file is opened correctly, I'm changing the file, press Ctrl+X, then Y, then Enter. That pops out:

```
[ Error writing /Applications/Utilities/Boot Camp Assistant.app/Contents/Info. ]
```

What should I do to save my changes?

Comment: Can you do `Ctrl+o` before `Ctrl+x`? This should write the file before you attempt to exit.

Comment: @Gavin The same error

Comment: This won't resolve the error, but it may give you a little more insight inside nano before you exit

Comment: @Gavin Maybe I don't understand what you mean but I see no difference

Comment: `Ctrl+o` is `write out`. This will not make you exit nano, but it will attempt to save the file. After attempting to write the file, nano will tell you at the bottom whether or not it was successful (and why if it wasn't).

Comment: @Gavin Ok, I press Ctrl+O, then Enter and I see the same text. `[ Error writing /Applications/Utilities/Boot Camp Assistant.app/Contents/Info. ]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126763/discussion-between-mark-and-gavin).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like modifying this file is somewhat of a hack that people are using. In about 10 seconds of Google'ing I found [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/OSXElCapitan/comments/3drepu/bootcamp_usb_windows_7_infoplist_hack/?st=iurb5bee&sh=96826eff), which explains a few ways you can get access to write to this file.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it